# How do I filter out lines of a text file that have length of 8 and ends in .com?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, grep

I have a list of a million domain names in `name.txt`

```
hello.com
abc.com
gogogo.us
goodbye.me
...
...
```

How do I pipe only domain names with 8 letters (including the `.com`) and only ends in `.com` to `names_new.txt`?

I'm looking for a simple command and not a script or anything.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` is the first tool to grab for pattern matching:

```
egrep -x '[a-z]{4}\.com' name.txt > newname.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 egrep "^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]\.com$" name.txt > names_new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Awk. The domain name is split by  `.` into fields.

First field is tested for length 4,as the `.com` adds another 4 chars.

The second field should contain `com`.

When both conditions are met, the line is printed.

```
cat name.txt |awk -F. '((length($1)==4)&&($2=="com")){print;}' > names_new.txt
```

Note: the line may found false positives if you have subdomains, eg:  `mail.com.nz`

Comment: [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). The awkish version of this would be `awk -F. 'length($1)==4&&$2=="com"&&NF==2' name.txt > names_new.txt` this would also sovle the false positives

Answer (score 0):

There may be domain names with dashes or numbers.
-i forces egrep to match regardless of case.

```
egrep -i "^[a-z0-9-]{4}\.com$" name.txt > names_new.txt
```